# Uploading a video via Google Picasa API

Tags: c#, api, video, picasa, google-photos

We have a working Picasa class to upload photos.

We have been trying to upload videos the same way but have been getting the error:
A direct media post of videos is currently not supported.

According to 
https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol#PostVideo one could use supported MIME type and upload videos the same way as photos.

As you can see in this method, we provide the correct MIME type:
https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/blob/master/ShareX.UploadersLib/ImageUploaders/Picasa.cs#L190

```
    public override UploadResult Upload(Stream stream, string fileName)
    {
        if (!CheckAuthorization()) return null;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AlbumID))
        {
            AlbumID = "default";
        }

        UploadResult ur = new UploadResult();

        string url = string.Format("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/albumid/" + AlbumID);
        string contentType = Helpers.GetMimeType(fileName);

        NameValueCollection headers = GetAuthHeaders();
        headers.Add("Slug", URLHelpers.URLEncode(fileName));

        ur.Response = SendRequest(HttpMethod.POST, url, stream, contentType, null, headers);

        if (ur.Response != null)
        {
            XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(ur.Response);

            XElement entry_element = xd.Element(AtomNS + "entry");

            if (entry_element != null)
            {
                XElement group_element = entry_element.Element(MediaNS + "group");

                if (group_element != null)
                {
                    XElement content_element = group_element.Element(MediaNS + "content");

                    if (content_element != null)
                    {
                        ur.ThumbnailURL = content_element.GetAttributeValue("url");

                        int last_slash_index = ur.ThumbnailURL.LastIndexOf(@"/");

                        ur.URL = ur.ThumbnailURL.Insert(last_slash_index, @"/s0");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return ur;
    }
}

public class PicasaAlbumInfo
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

When debugging, I can see for an mp4 file, we have"
contentType = "video/mp4"
This must be supported as per the Picasa Web Albums Data API guidelines.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I am writing in case of if still someone checking for this question;
Picasa API is deprecated, so Google Photos API is used for uploading images and videos. More details here: [Google Photos Api](https://developers.google.com/photos#PostVideo)